# How to reset chart.js chart yAxes count on tab change in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, chart.js

**I am using chart.js in Angular for display data.**

Is there any way to reset yAxes data on change tab?

Here's a link for [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyj7tt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) demo.

On load I am getting data like this.
[image]

**Than if i change tab than data are coming perfectly like below image.**
[image]

But when I change tab again to first tab at that time data is coming perfect but `yAxes` data is not changing therefore my chart is looks deferent from initial load. like below image.

[image]

**HTML CODE**

```
<mat-tab-group #tabgroup2 class="chart-filter-list" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event);">
    <mat-tab label="{{'This Week' | translate}}"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="{{'This Month' | translate}}"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="{{'This Year' | translate}}"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<div class="chart-body">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="recruitingChartData"
            [labels]="recruitingChartLabels"
            [options]="recruitingChartOptions"
            [legend]="recruitingChartLegend"
            [plugins]="recruitingChartPlugins"
            [colors]="recruitingChartColors"
            [chartType]="recruitingChartType">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

**ts file code**

```
onTabChanged($event) {
    const eventLabel = $event.tab.textLabel
    if (eventLabel == 'This Year'){
      this.tabSelectValue = 'yearly'
    }else if (eventLabel == 'This Month'){
      this.tabSelectValue = 'monthly'
    }else {
      this.tabSelectValue = 'weekly'
    }
    this.getDashboardMainData({});
}

// Recruiting Chart
public recruitingChartGetData : any = [];
public recruitingOpeningData : any = [];
public recruitingCandidateData : any = [];
public recruitingApplicationData : any = [];
public recruitingChartData: any = [
    { data: [ ], label: this.translate.instant('Job Openings') },
    { data: [ ], label: this.translate.instant('Candidates') },
    { data: [ ], label: this.translate.instant('Job Applications') },
];

public recruitingChartColors: any = [
    { // grey
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0)',
      borderColor: '#262f79',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // Blue
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0)',
      borderColor: '#fdb167',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    },
    { // red
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 71, 0)',
      borderColor: '#30c76f',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
    }

];
public recruitingChartLabels: any = [];
public recruitingChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    },
};
public recruitingChartLegend = false;
public recruitingChartType: any = 'line';
public recruitingChartPlugins = [];
```

Comment: Is it possible to get hold of rendered `chart` instance and call `chart.update()` method to redraw everything?

Comment: Not yet there is no any instance for that.

Comment: Hello @PankajParkar how to add `chart` instance?

Comment: Hello, is it possible for you to create a minimal reproducible problem on stackblitz? I would love to look into it.

Comment: Hello @PankajParkar Here, Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iyj7tt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also re-initialize `recruitingChartData` each time a new tab is selected. This can be done inside `getDashboardMainData` as follows.

```
async getDashboardMainData(request): Promise<void> {
  ...
  this.recruitingChartData.forEach(o => o.data = []);
```

Please take a look at your amended [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5omvtg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and see how it works.